# Php, почему не окрашивает слово привет?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    printf ("<span color='#%X%X%X'>Привет</span>", 65, 127, 245);
?>
```

Вот такой код, выводится просто слово "Привет", подскажите, что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно задать стиль `color`, а не атрибут.

```
printf("<span style='color: #%X%X%X'>Привет</span>", 65, 127, 245);
```

Comment: Спасибо)))))))))))